# Append new line with arguments

Tags: java, terminal, arguments, file-writing

My task is to append a new line into an existing text file from my terminal.

```
this.commands.put("-a" + ' ' + a, (args) -> {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try{
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(taskFilePath), true);
            byte[] byteArray = a.getBytes();

            fileOutputStream.write(byteArray);
        }
        finally {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }

        return """
                """ ;
```

When I write in the terminal it should work like this:
java filename -a "some words"
...and it should append those after -a to my txt but I can't figure it out..(filename isn't the problem)

Comment: Open a `FileWriter` in [append mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean))

Comment: @g00se still does not work

Comment: See example by @Kaan but chain a `PrintWriter` to it as writing platform-specific line separators is a. maybe not a good idea and b. you just to call `println`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, it's not clear what `this.commands.put()` is doing, or how that gets used later. As a guess, I suppose you're building a command to run later, and you aren't seeing expected results. It's also not clear what happens if any exceptions are thrown, which code gets a chance to catch any exceptions? Also, have you verified that `a.getBytes()` returns non-empty result? If `a` is empty to begin with, nothing will be written to a file.

For the goal itself – *"append a new line into an existing text file from my terminal"* – here's a very simple example showing how that could work. It takes all input arguments (whatever makes it through to `String[] args`) and writes each string to an output file at `/tmp/file.txt`, with each string followed by a newline (`\n`).

Also, this example uses `FileWriter` based on the following from [Javadoc for `FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html):

> *"FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using FileWriter."*

Here is an example of writing to a file using `FileWriter`. Again, it's a bit different from your exact question – I'm not breaking the command-line input looking for "-a" things. Instead, this focuses on the basic mechanics of writing to a file using command-line parameters.

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteToFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/tmp/file.txt", true)) {
            for (String arg : args) {
                writer.write(arg + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a run with output:

```
% java WriteToFile.java one two three
% cat /tmp/file.txt        
one
two
three
```